# Formulario validación checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Estoy haciendo un formulario y quiero que algunos campos sean requeridos. En los input tipo texto, numero y text area me funciona, en los checkbox y radio no. Aquí os dejo mi código.

```
<Form className='' style={{ width: '100%' }} onSubmit={handlerSubmit}>

    {data.map((v, i) => {
        return (
            <div key={i} className='mt-3'>
                {(v.opcional === false || (v.opcional === true && v.opcion && respuestas.includes(v.opcion))) &&
                    <>
                        <label className="block text-sm mb-1" htmlFor={v.pregunta}>
                            <span className='font-semibold'>{t(`${v.pregunta}`)}</span> <span className="text-red-500">*</span>
                            {(v.tipo === 'checkbox') &&
                                <span className='italic  text-xs'>({t("formExtra.respuestaMultiple")})</span>
                            }
                        </label>

                        {/* <Form.Group className="mb-2  text-sm" controlId="formBasicCheckbox"> */}
                        {v.tipo === 'radio' || v.tipo === 'checkbox' ?
                            <Form.Group className="mb-2  text-sm" controlId="formBasicCheckbox" required={v.opcional === false ? true : false} >
                    
                                {Array.isArray(v.respuestas) && v.respuestas.map((x, j) => (
                                    <div key={j}>
                                        <Form.Check
                                            type={v.tipo}
                                            name={v.preguntaTxt}
                                            id={v.preguntaTxt + j}
                                            value={x.txt}
                                            label={t(`${x.trd}`)}
                                            onChange={(e) => handlerCheck(e)}

                                        />
                                    </div>
                                ))
                                }

                            </Form.Group>
                            :
                            v.tipo === 'textarea' ?

                                <textarea id={v.preguntaTxt} name={v.preguntaTxt} className={`form-input w-full`} required={v.opcional === false ? true : false}></textarea>
                                :
                                <input id={v.preguntaTxt} name={v.preguntaTxt} className={`form-input ${v.tipo === 'text' ? 'w-full' : 'w-20'}`} type={v.tipo} required={v.opcional === false ? true : false} />
                        }

                        {/* </Form.Group> */}

                    </>
                }
            </div>
        );
    })}

</Form>
```

Necesito que sean requeridas las que pone `v.opcional = false`. No sé si control id hace algo o hay algo que estoy haciendo mal, pero el tipo checkbox y el tipo radio aunque no estén marcadas me guarda el formulario y necesito que no lo guarde, como en los input.